# Ambigous reference to member ' evaluateWithObject ' swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nspredicate

```
 let emailTestPredicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES[c] %@", regStr)

 return emailTestPredicate.evaluateWithObject(emailStr)
```

`emailStr` is a `String` but the error pops as:

> Ambigous reference to member evaluateWithObject

Comment: Is `emailStr` a string or an optional string?

Comment: Can you provide the whole method?

Comment: try this `return (emailTestPredicate!.evaluateWithObject(emailStr))` in the place of `return emailTestPredicate.evaluateWithObject(emailStr)`

Comment: its not an optional string

Comment: Then unwrap the predicate as suggested in the answer. *Ambiguous* indicates often unexpected optional types.